# How do MAC addresses found in Ethernet packets relate to the TCP/IP Packets?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I was doing a lab and wrote a C program which reads all `AF_PACKET` `SOCK_RAW` packets - meaning OSI layer 2 Ethernet frames. The program logs the contents of the Ethernet header (MAC addresses), IP header, TCP header, and so-on.

This raised a question - If the Ethernet layer is the lowest before the physical layer, how are the MAC addresses resolved in a layer below the IP address layer? For example, if my machine in California sends TCP/IP packets to yours in New York, are the MAC addresses in the Ethernet headers corresponding to our actual MAC addresses or just the MAC addresses between our separate computers and their respective routers?

I'm aware that there's a transaction in which a machine identifies itself via MAC address to the router and is given an IP address, but every single Ethernet packet has a source and destination MAC address, and I'm confused as to which machines those MAC addresses correlate to because there's no way my machine could have your machine's MAC address before first contacting your machine via IP address.

Comment: "_If the Ethernet layer is the lowest before the physical layer, how are the MAC addresses resolved in a layer below the IP address layer?_" ARP (Address Resolution Prtotocol - [RFC 826](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc826)), but you are asking on the wrong SE site.

Comment: Note that IP protocol requires IP addresses to go around the world, but Ethernet is a Link protocol, where each device just knows its neighbourhood (and can use broadcast to discover it, if it doesn't know it). There is one link between my machine and the wireless router; another link between that router and the next router, etc. At each link, the IP packet gets a new Ethernet frame. Just like in a relay race, the payload is the same, but each link only knows to accept from the last runner, and to pass it to the next one.

Comment: @Amadan So a new Ethernet packet with a new Ethernet header by the same or very similar payload is created every single time the packet hits a new machine, which could be dozens or more times between us? Is there any good literature on this that goes into some details? I find it fascinating and missing from most networking education I've read so far which tends to place all focus on IP and above.

Comment: @the_endian There isn't even always ethernet between two links; other layer 2 headers are possible (sonet, atm). However, ethernet is the most common one nowadays. You can imagine, that the ethernet addresses are rewritten rather than a new packet is created.

Comment: Yup, I misspoke, it's not always Ethernet. But basically IP is like a relay race - hopping from one server to another - and MAC addresses change at each stop. Your IP packet definitely doesn't know the MAC address of its destination, just of the next hop.

Comment: @Ctx, "_ethernet is the most common one nowadays._" Actually, more devices are now shipped with Wi-Fi than ethernet interfaces.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, but WiFi is typically represented as Ethernet at the packet layer. WiFi devices have MAC addresses assigned to them.

Comment: Wi-Fi frames and ethernet frames are very different. Token ring, FDDI, etc. also use MAC addresses, but they are not ethernet either.

Comment: @RonMaupin Now I'm a bit more confused because I just ran my raw socket sniffer listening for ALL ETHER traffic on AF_PACKET socket with SOCK_RAW. I had it listen to my wifi device and the program collected a bunch of Ethernet packets and properly parsed them... So am I working with Ethernet or not here?

Comment: It sounds like the frames were "normalized." The ethernet frame header is very simple, and there are two MAC addresses in it. Wi-Fi has multiple frame types, and a regular data frame will have things like control information and space for four MAC addresses. It sounds like what you are using is doing the same thing as a translating bridge (WAP) would do to convert frames between ethernet and Wi-Fi.

Comment: @RonMaupin WiFi is Ethernet, when talking about the Datalink-Layer. Yes, there is additional information between the WiFi-Client and AP, but this is only for media access control (somewhere between osi layer 1 and 2). Remember, OSI is not a strict model. But in general, Ethernet-Frames are transmitted, also when using WiFi

Comment: @Ctx, not at all. The frames are the data-link PDUs (protocol data units), and Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) frames are very different than ethernet (IEEE 802.3) frames. Other IEEE protocols, e.g. FDDI (IEEE 802.8), have frames that are much closer to ethernet, but neither are they ethernet.

Comment: Don't forget protocols as SLIP or PPP that are point to point and don't need (and don't use) hardware addresses to direct packets to.

Comment: @LuisColorado, and frame relay uses DLCI, ATM uses VPI/VCI, and HDLC uses nothing. The IEEE LAN protocols use MAC addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin, nope, HDLC uses a single address bit to differentiate terminal from network devices.  What do you pretend with your comment? I'm not going to discuss the exact implementations of all the different media protocols.  The reason is that frame relay, atm, etc. are not actually point to point protocols, and you can have several channels attached to a single interface, but what I intended to say is that a point to point protocol doesn't need to address the target, because there's only one.

Comment: @LuisColorado, that depends on the implementation (each vendor does it differently). For example, Cisco uses the broadcast address as the destination address of every frame, so, in practice, there is no actual address used.

Answer (score 1):

They simply don't relate.  The mac address normally comes with the hardware device, and the IP address is selected by the network administrator (or network provider).

To convert one to the other, two network protocols are used:

- ARP ((A)ddress (R)esolution (P)rotocol) is a protocol of mandatory implementation in almost every ethernet based installation.  It allows you to get the matching MAC address for a high level IP local network address.  It's based on broadcasting and it's normally used when you don't know (yet) the ethernet address of a host attached to the local net.  For remote hosts you don't need their mac address, but the address of the gateway that drives packets to those targets.
- RARP ((R)everse ARP)  is not as frequently installed.  It allows to get the IP address from de MAC address.  It's normally implemented in networks where automatic configuration is implemented.  You normally use it to get **your own IP address** (normally there's a simple mean to obtain your hardware MAC address, but there's no such simple way to get your IP address if you have not stored it in permanent storage)  This protocol is of very low use, as it has been superseeded by DHCP or BOOTP protocols, that allow not only to get the IP address, but more parameters.

R/ARP normally works the same way (both protocols): the querying host broadcasts a request packet with the known part of the mapping filled and the unknwn part unfilled to the local network, and the host that has the requested address (or the server/s in case of RARP, as this protocol is used for configuration purposes) answers the request.

To not have to use this costly protocol (a broadcast moves a lot of activity in the network, as normally all hosts get notice of the broadcast and do some processing on behalf of it) the ARP client software normally maintains a cache table of mapping between MAC addresses and IP addresses, avoiding the re-broadcasting in case the entry is alive (entries have a time to live entry, so they must be refreshed, normally 15min.)